Why validation doesn't reset?
I'm trying to reset the error-state from a JSF component.
I saw a lot of questions about it, but I would like to try to avoid javascript/ajax if possible.
The component:
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-lg-4 #{identifier.valid ? '' : 'has-error'}">
  ...label
   <h:inputText styleClass="form-control"
   id="identifier"
      binding="#{identifier}"
      value="#{bb.someValue}" maxlength="5" >
        <f:attribute name="field" value="validateIdentifier" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="identifier" styleClass="msg msg-errore" style="font-weight: bold;" />
</div>

The validator:
public void validateForm(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate, Object value) {
String element = (String) toValidate.getAttributes().get("field");

if ("validateIdentifier".equals(element)) {
String identif = (String) value;

if (identif.length() > 5 || !identif.matches("[0-9]+")) {
((UIInput) toValidate).setValid(false);
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("SOME MESSAGE");
context.addMessage(toValidate.getClientId(context), message);
}
}
}

I tried to clear the messages but apparently it's not the way.
The validation process works just fine, but if an error has shown I can't see how to reset the error (style and message).
The managed bean is session scoped and everything is in there.

So simply reloading the page also doesn't work? Do you anywhere have a binding referencing a session scoped bean property such as binding="#{bb.someComponent}" instead of a page variable such as binding="#{identifier}"?

@BalusC reloading the page means forwarding back to the dashboard (I don't know who implemented that and why) but let me clarify: I do have an error on validation fail, but as I have a validation that do not fails it disappears (red style and message). What I need is a reset button for clearing the form

@BalusC for the binding property, is not referencing any bb property, just the field (I read that it can be used for the style purpose)

@BalusC I found a workaround based on your words: I just added an <h:button/> that reloads the view to his original state (if I'm not wrong)
